# Visual Code auto format places new lines when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I use the format document in Visual Code (note, **Visual Code** and NOT Visual Studio), it will change my code like this:

**Before Auto Format:**

```
fetchEmployees = async () => {
    await this.props.getEmployeesInProject();
}

fetchAssignments = async () => {
    await this.props.getAssignmentsInProject();
}
```

**After Auto Format:**

```
fetchEmployees = async() => {
    await this
        .props
        .getEmployeesInProject();
}

fetchAssignments = async() => {
    await this
        .props
        .getAssignmentsInProject();
}
```

What's odd is that this one stays fine:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchEmployees();
    await this.fetchAssignments();
}
```

Does anyone know which format setting I need to fix for this?

Comment: The reason it does this is because you are chaining multiple calls together, having them each on their own line increases readability. As far as I'm aware there is no way to configure the built-in formatter but you can install your own such as [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) and configure it as you wish.

Comment: I found out it was react-beautify that was causing this so I uninstalled it and it stopped doing it on multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

I had react-beautify installed as an extension, which was causing the auto format to place them on new lines.